# Weird Requests/DefaultSavedRequests from other websites in my app?

Tags: apache, spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee, spring-security

greetings all
i am using spring security 3.0.2
and i am using apache,tomcat
i was discovering the sessions on my web app
and found out too many sessions with used time=0
and the description of one of them was something like:

```
Attribute name : SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY  
Attribute value : DefaultSavedRequest[http://someStrangeWebsite.com/myappname/]
```

i am wondering why such a weird behaviour occurs ?

also i added a filter in the app to debug the incoming request urls
and i found out that many request urls where something like:
http://someStrangeWebsite.com/myappname/

which is also very strange to me.
can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Isn't `someStrangeWebsite.com` a primary DNS name for the host you are running your Tomcat on?

Comment: those weird requests are random, they don't come from such static web sites, they are many different requests from different websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps somebody sends HTTP requests with

```
Host: someStrangeWebsite.com
```

to your site. Since Tomcat doesn't know DNS names of the server it's running on, these requests look valid.

Comment: didn't understand it fully, but how to avoid it anyway ?